# MediaMetadataCompact getRating

Tags: android, media, mediabrowser

In my media app, I keep all the media items as MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem
I'm adding a rating to these items.
To read the rating from a MediaItemCompact, Android provides

public RatingCompat getRating (String key)

what is the key parameter ? and how should I use this API to simple read the average users' rating ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mediaMetadataCompact.getRating(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_USER_RATING);` to get user rating.

Refer:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/MediaMetadataCompat.html#METADATA_KEY_USER_RATING

https://www.javatips.net/api/android-support-v4-master/src/java/android/support/v4/media/MediaMetadataCompat.java